# Firefox profile with webdriver and ruby - unknown option error

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, webdriver

Ruby 2.2.5

Upgraded Gems to the following:
    -Cucumber 2.4.0
    -Selenium Webdriver 3.0.0
    -rake 11.3.0
    -json 2.0.2

And just upgraded to Firefox 47.  Installed Gecko and now I am getting the following error when trying to run in Firefox

```
unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x40bba78 @model=nil, @native_events=true, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={"plugin.default.state"=>2}, @extensions={}>} (ArgumentError)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why?!

Comment: Try firefox 40.0 that worked for me, it might just work.

Comment: firefox 46 but not 47 worked for me. here is the url to the firefox binary which you can direct selenium to: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/firefox-46.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Does this mean there is a known issue?  Ideally I need to be testing against the latest browsers, I've already missed a bug found in 47 as I had to stay on Firefox 46 until Selenium fixed a bug with 2.53 and 47!